# use of Bluetooth messaging on android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bluetooth

I am an amateur developer and i am developing an app in which my android phone communicates with my microcontroller via bluetooth. For this purose i am using the the google sample bluetooth chat app as a module(without any edit) in my project and my app moves to this module from my basic or default module using intent. Now the problem is when my app moves to an activity in this module the top toolbar doesnt apper. The same code when executed independently shows the toolbar (Actionbar). I am not able to understand the problem.Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the theme of the Activity from the sample bluetooth app that you have imported.

If you use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"` or another post jelly bean theme that does not specify "NoActionBar" then you should have the native ActionBar added to your activity. Make this change in AndroidManifest.xml in the `<activity>` tag.

Comment: Sorry! Please post more info about your manifest and layout files.